# Can not log in - Login failed for user 'username'

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am migrating my ASP.NET Framework application to ASP.NET Core

I'm having issues connecting to my production database.

My local SQLite database works fine.

The issue comes when I try to connect to my remote SQLExpress database.

The error message is

> login failed for user 'username'

The first most obvious thing is, a faulty username or password, but I'm copying the connection string from my web.config file and pasting it into the appsettings.json file!

When I try to connect to the database with the .NET Framework version, it connects fine.

If I connect via SSMS and use SQL Server Auth, I can log in with the same copied and pasted credentials.

I believe the relevant parts of the code are

```
public void Configure(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true).Build();
    var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString(GetConnectionString());

    if (IsTestDatabase())
    {                
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionString);
    }
    else
    {  
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString); //I ASSUME THIS WORKS WITH SQL EXPRESS
    }
}
```

and the relevant part of my appsettings.json file is

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "TestingDatabase": "Data Source=c:\\MyWebsite\\datastorage.db;",
    "LiveDatabase": "Data Source=111.111.111.111\\sqlexpress;initial catalog=DatabaseName;persist security info=True;user id=username;password=password;multipleactiveresultsets=True;"
},
```

I am able to create an instance of my database context, but not query any data.

```
var dc = new DalCf.Entities();
var account = dc.Accounts.AsNoTracking().Single(); //this is the line that throws an exception
```

Does it look like I've done anything wrong from what I've shared?

Comment: Is the "Migration" folder  missing in your project directory?

Comment: I'm lost by your question @vvvv4d. The migration folder is irrelevant I *think* because it will depend on what project starts up - for example, if a test in my test project needed to connect to the database, are you suggesting that too would need a `migration` folder?

Comment: When you successfully connect in SSMS are you using the IP from the connectionstring or the server name?

Comment: The same as what is the appsettings.json file. I log onto my vps, open ssms and enter the ip address \sqlexpress

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions: are you using multiple `appsettings.json` config files? You're using .NET Core and not the old ASP.NET anymore with `web.config` where you might have to put multiple test and production connection strings there. With .NET Core, you can declare multiple `appsettings.json` config files with corresponding environments, e.g., `appsettings.stagging.json`, `appsettings.test.json`, `appsettings.production.json`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1. You don't have to switch connection strings programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can connect successfully in SSMS and the connection strings are valid there is something wrong with the mechanism that is used to get the connection string:

`configuration.GetConnectionString(GetConnectionString())`

Your `GetConnectionString()` method used on the above line doesn't seem to be returning the correct connection string.

Review what the `GetConnectionString()` returns (it could be an issue with certain characters such as if your password uses non-alphanumeric characters for example)

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions took another shot at this. Let me know if this works. If not let's hop in chat and get this figured out!

Comment: I think I can share this - my password had a £ sign. For some reason, whilst it worked fine in .NET Framework, .NET core does not like it. WIll give bounty tomorrow, when it lets me (have to wait 21 hours). Big thank you

Comment: Did you find that by inspecting what values `configuration.GetConnectionString` had and you noticed the missing character making the password incorrect?

Comment: You could get the pound to work if you used `&pound;` instead of the actual character itself. You need to use the html entity names in the json. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp